# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Elementor\Controls_Manager' not found

Tags: php, wordpress, elementor

I'm having this error in my wordpress website.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Elementor\Controls_Manager' not found in /home/vol15_6/epizy.com/epiz_26758330/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/elementor/includes/autoloader.php:132 Stack trace: #0 /home/vol15_6/epizy.com/epiz_26758330/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/elementor/includes/autoloader.php(78): Elementor\Autoloader::init_classes_map() #1 /home/vol15_6/epizy.com/epiz_26758330/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/elementor/includes/autoloader.php(252): Elementor\Autoloader::get_classes_map() #2 /home/vol15_6/epizy.com/epiz_26758330/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/elementor/includes/autoloader.php(305): Elementor\Autoloader::load_class('Core\\Logger\\Man...') #3 [internal function]: Elementor\Autoloader::autoload('Elementor\\Core\\...') #4 /home/vol15_6/epizy.com/epiz_26758330/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/elementor/includes/plugin.php(708): spl_autoload_call('Elementor\\Core\\...') #5 /home/vol15_6/epizy.com/epiz_26758330/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/elementor/includes/plugin.php(487): Elementor\Plugin->__construct() #6 /home/vol15_6/epizy.com/e in /home/vol15_6/epizy.com/epiz_26758330/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/elementor/includes/autoloader.php on line 132
```

[image]

Comment: Have you had a look at this: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/303752/elementor-fatal-error-class-elementor-widget-base-not-found

Comment: That solution is only for older elementor version 1.0.0. I'm using the latest Version: 3.0.12

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution was to downgrade `elementor` to an older version of `3.0.11`.